# Save a managed file with cURL

Tags: 7, files

I want to save a managed file from an external site. Previously, I've used this code:

```
$managed = TRUE; // Whether or not to create a Drupal file record
$image_file = system_retrieve_file($product['img'], 'public://product-img-' . time() . '.jpg', $managed);
if ($image_file) {
  $file = file_load(db_query('SELECT MAX(fid) FROM {file_managed}')->fetchField());
  $item['field_image']['und'][0] = (array) $file;
}
```

However, it's throwing 403 errors for me so I decided to use cURL in my PHP code to get this image:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://g02.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB15eliFVXXXXbKaXXXq6xXFXXXa/Original-Blackberry-Z10-Dual-Core-4-2-TouchScreen-2GB-RAM-16GB-ROM-8MP-Camera-Blackberry-os.jpg');
$fp = fopen('test.jpg', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

With cURL, it works correctly, and I can get the image. How can I save this data as a Drupal managed file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`file_save_data()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_save_data/7.x) will take the contents of a file and place into a location specified by a file URI. In your example, you can take your downloaded **test.jpg**, retrieve its contents, and have `file_save_data()` do the rest.

```
// Assuming same cwd where curl & fopen was executed.
$image_file = file_save_data(file_get_contents('test.jpg'), 'public://test.jpg', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

// test.jpg will be placed/overwritten into your managed file system.
// $image_file contains the Drupal file object.
```

Comment: I did it before your asnwer with `$file_name = 'public://product-img-' . time() . '.jpg';
            $file_content = file_get_contents($product['img']);
            $file_temp = file_save_data($file_content,$file_name);
            ym($file_temp,'message');
            if($file_temp){
//                $file = file_load(db_query('SELECT MAX(fid) FROM {file_managed}')->fetchField());
                $item['field_image']['und'][0] = (array) $file_temp;
            }`.
exactly something like your answer