# How to save file with custom form?

Tags: 7, forms, files

I try to use that script in my Drupal site https://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form

I did not use drupal form api. I used my html same with that script.

I created 2 pages with hook_menu.

On first page I use that script to upload files.
That script sends files via ajax to 2. page. But I could not save files as managed file.

On second page I save datas as json to logs to see what i get in that file.
That is an example json;

```
 {"name":"aa.jpg","type":"image\/jpeg","tmp_name":"\/tmp\/phpWkCoI6","error":0,"size":8575}
```

How can I save files as managed file on second page?

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/207226/67770

Answer (score 2):

I solved like that

```
$file_name = $file['name'];
$file_get = file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']);
$new_file = file_save_data($file_get, 'public://images/'.$file_name);
```